# Why is this derivative not being calculated automatically?

Tags: sympy

I am trying to use differentiation on a function on sympy.

This is the code that i am using.

```py
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = 5*x**9 - 4*x**3 + 21 - 1/x
print("Expression : {}".format(expr))

expr_diff = Derivative(expr, x)
print("Derivative of expression with respect to x : {}".format(expr_diff))
print("Value of the derivative : {}".format(expr_diff.doit()))
```

when it outputs

Expression : `5*x**9 - 4*x**3 + 21 - 1/x`

Derivative of expression with respect to x : `Derivative(5*x**9 - 4*x**3 + 21 - 1/x, x)`
Value of the derivative : `45*x**8 - 12*x**2 + x**(-2)`

Is there a way to get the derivative directly without using `doit`?

Comment: What where you expecting? That is the exact correct result, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Derivative` creates an unevaluated expression which, as you see, is evaluated with `doit`. If you don't want the evaluated form, use `expr.diff()` (which also accepts variable of differentiation and order to be specified:

```py
>>> expr.diff()
45*x**8 - 12*x**2 + x**(-2)
>>> expr.diff(x,x)==expr.diff(x,2), expr.diff(x,x)
(True, 2*(180*x**7 - 12*x - 1/x**3))
```